# When using three ModuleLoaders my application sometimes fails with Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3

My problem occurs when I attempt to use more than 2 module loaders. My first problem was when I tried using more than 1. Below you can see my workaround. I'm still somewhat new to Modules so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious here. What kills me is how it sometimes works but other times doesn't?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at ModuleInfo/completeHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\modules\ModuleManager.as:717]
```

**My Application:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            import mx.core.Application;
            import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
            import mx.modules.ModuleManager;

            private var popUpManager:PopUpManager;          
            private var podXml:XML;

            private var moduleIsReady:Boolean;

            private function getSwf():String
            {
                return "location/SimpleModule.swf";
            }

            private function onModuleUnload(moduleEvent:ModuleEvent):void
            {
                // Had to release in order to get 2 to work, now it breaks on 3
                var info:IModuleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule(getSwf());
                info.release();
                info = null;
                trace("module unloaded");
            }

            private function onModuleReady(moduleEvent:ModuleEvent):void
            {           
                // Module loaded

                // moduleIsReady = true; //used as a flag for child to know when the module itself is ready
                //var ichild:MyInterface = module.child as MyInterface
                //if (module.child != null)
                //{
                //  ichild.doStuff();
                //}                         
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:ModuleLoader url="{getSwf()}" id="module" ready="onModuleReady(event)" unload="onModuleUnload(event)" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"/>
        <mx:ModuleLoader url="{getSwf()}" id="module1" ready="onModuleReady(event)" unload="onModuleUnload(event)" x="50" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
        <mx:ModuleLoader url="{getSwf()}" id="module2" ready="onModuleReady(event)" unload="onModuleUnload(event)" x="50" y="450" width="100" height="100"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

**My Module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module layout="absolute" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
           width="100%" height="100%"
           backgroundColor="0xFF0000">
</mx:Module>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by appending a timestamp to the end of my URLs in the form of a query string but I'd like to know why this was required.